# Why does Django serve my page as a download?

Tags: django, http, fastcgi

I have a Web app written in Python+Django. On my machine, it works fine; as soon as I push it into production, it starts acting up.

For some reason, my login screen loads fine. But, as soon as I try to log in, I get the homepage either as a download (if I turn gzip middleware on), or as a [plain text page containing the response](http://pastebin.com/pL6REBAf).

My production server runs Python 2.6.8, and my Django version is 1.4.1-final. I don't have access to mod_wsgi, so I use CGI instead. Here's my [.htaccess](http://pastebin.com/Ypsze2Lp) and [FCGI script](http://pastebin.com/dR9LsZSL). It's really just a cheap shared hosting plan, but I have another Django site there that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems unlikely, but setting a different content_type in your response can make this happen sometimes, e.g.

> > > response = HttpResponse(my_data, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
> > >       response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="foo.xls"'

[(Django Docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment)

Can you link a line or two of your response call?

Comment: It's probably something like that, somewhere; yet, I don't recall ever needing anything like it, and a search of my codebase returns nothing. The login page uses a function-based generic view, while the homepage (which renders as text) uses a custom view; I'll look at that.

Comment: Here's my [custom view](http://pastebin.com/ecgGyX6w). Maybe it's due to using `render` instead of `render_to_response`. Gonna check it out now.

Comment: Ahh. It was that rogue `print` statement I used for crude debugging. I'm an ass!

Comment: @egasimus Please write directly to your question that it is closed yet. Nobody should waste time by it more.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it's due to the fact you expose it as a cgi, but you use django.core.servers.fastcgi. Apparently django isn't supposed to be exposed as plain CGI, but some tried, found this blogpost : http://joemaller.com/1467/django-via-cgi-on-shared-hosting/

Comment: Wasn't me who down voted, but flup, which Django uses for implementing its FASTCGI bridge, can actually downgrade to running as CGI if it detects that it was run in context of a CGI script. Thus as long as wasn't setup in a way that would prevent it, it may technically work. That said, running Django as CGI is a very bad idea because the load time of Django and the application would be even worse than the actual Python interpreter startup time, so response times would be really bad.

Comment: Still, why would some pages load, and some not? And there's another site running there with mostly the same settings (it doesn't use any form of login, though)